# NLOG: Creating multiple instances of same class writing log to same file

Tags: c#, nlog

I am trying to get used to NLOG and finding it difficult in setting log files for multiple instances of a same class. Each class is created on a different thread. Please find below the sample code:

```
    {
        ILogger mLogger;
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SecondName { get; set; }
        private string mFilePath = @"C:\Logs\";
        public test(string name, string secondname)
        {
            var target = new FileTarget(name) { FileName = mFilePath + name + ".txt" };
            var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
            config.AddRule(LogLevel.Info, LogLevel.Info, target);
            LogManager.Configuration = config;
            mLogger = LogManager.GetLogger(name);
            LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
            mLogger.Info("Hi from :" + name);
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => { new test("Stuart", "Broad"); })).Start();
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                new test("John", "Smith");
            })).Start();
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                new test("Virat", "Kohli");
            })).Start();
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                new test("Christiano", "Ronaldo");
            })).Start();

            new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
                {
                    new test("Pat", "cummins");
                })).Start();
            Console.Read();
        }
```

and output is :
**2020-03-03 11:36:56.9404|INFO|Christiano|Hi from :Christiano
2020-03-03 11:36:56.9404|INFO|Stuart|Hi from :Stuart
2020-03-03 11:36:56.9404|INFO|John|Hi from :John
2020-03-03 11:36:56.9404|INFO|Virat|Hi from :Virat
2020-03-03 11:36:56.9404|INFO|Pat|Hi from :Pat**

from just one file Christiano.txt

Could somebody please help me in configuring this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LogManager.Configuration` is a static variable. When you assign it then you affect everyone else.

Instead give a unique Logger for each thread. The same FileTarget can handle multiple Loggers.

```
{
    ILogger mLogger;
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public test(string name, string secondname)
    {
        mLogger = LogManager.GetLogger(name);
        mLogger.Info("Hi from :" + name);
    }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string mFilePath = @"C:\Logs\";
        var target = new FileTarget(name) { FileName = Path.Combine(mFilePath, "${logger}.txt") };
        var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
        config.AddRule(LogLevel.Info, LogLevel.Info, target);
        LogManager.Configuration = config;

        new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => { new test("Stuart", "Broad"); })).Start();
        new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            new test("John", "Smith");
        })).Start();
        new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            new test("Virat", "Kohli");
        })).Start();
        new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            new test("Christiano", "Ronaldo");
        })).Start();

        new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                new test("Pat", "cummins");
            })).Start();
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Alternative then you could [assign names to the threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.name), and make use of the NLog `${threadname}` instead of `${logger}` in FileName-Layout.

Yet another alternative is to create a scope using NLog [MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.SetScoped("TestName", name)](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/MDLC-Layout-Renderer) and use `${mdlc:TestName}` in FileName-Layout. This will also allow you to flow the initial context to async Tasks.